# Play Json API: Convert a JsArray to a JsResult[Seq[Element]]

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a `JsArray` which contains `JsValue` objects representing two different types of entities - some of them represent *nodes*, the other part represents *edges*.

On the Scala side, there are already case classes named `Node` and `Edge` whose supertype is `Element`. The goal is to transform the `JsArray` (or `Seq[JsValue]`) to a collection that contains the Scala types, e.g. `Seq[Element]` (=> contains objects of type `Node` and `Edge`).

I have defined `Read` for the case classes:

```
implicit val nodeReads: Reads[Node] = // ...

implicit val edgeReads: Reads[Edge] = // ...
```

Apart from that, there is the first step of a `Read` for the `JsArray` itself:

```
implicit val elementSeqReads = Reads[Seq[Element]](json => json match {
  case JsArray(elements) => ???
  case _ => JsError("Invalid JSON data (not a json array)")
})
```

The part with the question marks is responsible for creating a `JsSuccess(Seq(node1, edge1, ...)` if all elements of the `JsArray` are valid nodes and edges or a `JsError` if this is not the case.

However, I'm not sure how to do this in an elegant way.

The logic to distinguish between nodes and edges *could* look like this:

```
def hasType(item: JsValue, elemType: String) =
   (item \ "elemType").asOpt[String] == Some(elemType)

val result = elements.map {
  case n if hasType(n, "node") => // use nodeReads
  case e if hasType(e, "edge") => // use edgeReads
  case _ => JsError("Invalid element type")
}
```

The thing is that I don't know how to deal with `nodeReads` / `edgeReads` at this point. Of course I could call their `validate` method directly, but then `result` would have the type `Seq[JsResult[Element]]`. So eventually I would have to check if there are any `JsError` objects and delegate them somehow to the top (remember: one invalid array element should lead to a `JsError` overall). If there are no errors, I still have to produce a `JsSuccess[Seq[Element]]` based on `result`.

Maybe it would be a better idea to avoid the calls to `validate` and work temporarily with `Read` instances instead. But I'm not sure how to "merge" all of the `Read` instances at the end (e.g. in simple case class mappings, you have a bunch of calls to `JsPath.read` (which returns `Read`) and in the end, `validate` produces one single result based on all those Read instances that were concatenated using the `and` keyword).

**edit:** A little bit more information.

First of all, I should have mentioned that the case classes `Node` and `Edge` basically have the same structure, at least for now. At the moment, the only reason for separate classes is to gain more type safety.

A `JsValue` of an element has the following JSON-representation:

```
{
    "id" : "aet864t884srtv87ae",
    "type" : "node", // <-- type can be 'node' or 'edge'
    "name" : "rectangle",
    "attributes": [],
    ...
}
```

The corresponding case class looks like this (note that the type attribute  we've seen above is *not* an attribute of the class - instead it's represented by the type of the class -> `Node`).

```
case class Node(
  id: String,
  name: String,
  attributes: Seq[Attribute],
  ...) extends Element
```

The `Read` is as follows:

```
implicit val nodeReads: Reads[Node] = (
      (__ \ "id").read[String] and
      (__ \ "name").read[String] and
      (__ \ "attributes").read[Seq[Attribute]] and
      ....
    ) (Node.apply _)
```

everything looks the same for `Edge`, at least for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining `elementReads` as

```
implicit val elementReads = new Reads[Element]{
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Element] =
      json.validate(
        Node.nodeReads.map(_.asInstanceOf[Element]) orElse
        Edge.edgeReads.map(_.asInstanceOf[Element])
      )
}
```

and import that in scope, Then you should be able to write

```
json.validate[Seq[Element]]
```

If the structure of your json is not enough to differentiate between `Node` and `Edge`, you could enforce it in the reads for each type.

Based on a simplified `Node` and `Edge` case class (only to avoid any unrelated code confusing the answer)

```
case class Edge(name: String) extends Element
case class Node(name: String) extends Element
```

The default reads for  these case classes would be derived by

```
Json.reads[Edge]
Json.reads[Node]
```

respectively. Unfortunately since both case classes have the same structure these reads would ignore the `type` attribute in the json and happily translate a node json into an `Edge` instance or the opposite.

Lets have a look at how we could express the constraint on `type` all by itself :

```
 def typeRead(`type`: String): Reads[String] = {
    val isNotOfType = ValidationError(s"is not of expected type ${`type`}")
    (__ \ "type").read[String].filter(isNotOfType)(_ == `type`)
  }
```

This method builds a Reads[String] instance which will attempt to find a `type` string attribute in the provided json. It will then filter the `JsResult` using the custom validation error `isNotOfType` if the string parsed out of the json doesn't matched the expected `type` passed as argument of the method. Of course if the `type` attribute is not a string in the json, the Reads[String] will return an error saying that it expected a String.

Now that we have a read which can enforce the value of the `type` attribute in the json, all we have to do is to build a reads for each value of type which we expect and compose it with the associated case class reads. We can used `Reads#flatMap` for that ignoring the input since the parsed string is not useful for our case classes.

```
object Edge {
  val edgeReads: Reads[Edge] = 
    Element.typeRead("edge").flatMap(_ => Json.reads[Edge])
}
object Node {
  val nodeReads: Reads[Node] = 
    Element.typeRead("node").flatMap(_ => Json.reads[Node])
}
```

Note that if the constraint on `type` fails the `flatMap` call will be bypassed.

The question remains of where to put the method `typeRead`, in this answer I initially put it in the `Element` companion object along with the `elementReads` instance as in the code below.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

trait Element
object Element {
  implicit val elementReads = new Reads[Element] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Element] =
      json.validate(
        Node.nodeReads.map(_.asInstanceOf[Element]) orElse
        Edge.edgeReads.map(_.asInstanceOf[Element])
      )
  }
  def typeRead(`type`: String): Reads[String] = {
    val isNotOfType = ValidationError(s"is not of expected type ${`type`}")
    (__ \ "type").read[String].filter(isNotOfType)(_ == `type`)
  }
}
```

This is actually a pretty bad place to define `typeRead` : 
 - it has nothing specific to `Element`
 - it introduces a circular dependency between the `Element`companion object and both `Node` and `Edge` companion objects

I'll let you think up of the correct location though :)

The specification proving it all works together :

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.data.validation.ValidationError

class ElementSpec extends Specification {

  "Element reads" should {
    "read an edge json as an edge" in {
      val result: JsResult[Element] = edgeJson.validate[Element]
      result.isSuccess should beTrue
      result.get should beEqualTo(Edge("myEdge"))
    }
    "read a node json as an node" in {
      val result: JsResult[Element] = nodeJson.validate[Element]
      result.isSuccess should beTrue
      result.get should beEqualTo(Node("myNode"))
    }
  }
  "Node reads" should {
    "read a node json as an node" in {
      val result: JsResult[Node] = nodeJson.validate[Node](Node.nodeReads)
      result.isSuccess should beTrue
      result.get should beEqualTo(Node("myNode"))
    }
    "fail to read an edge json as a node" in {
      val result: JsResult[Node] = edgeJson.validate[Node](Node.nodeReads)
      result.isError should beTrue
      val JsError(errors) = result
      val invalidNode = JsError.toJson(Seq(
        (__ \ "type") -> Seq(ValidationError("is not of expected type node"))
      ))
      JsError.toJson(errors) should beEqualTo(invalidNode)
    }
  }

  "Edge reads" should {
    "read a edge json as an edge" in {
      val result: JsResult[Edge] = edgeJson.validate[Edge](Edge.edgeReads)
      result.isSuccess should beTrue
      result.get should beEqualTo(Edge("myEdge"))
    }
    "fail to read a node json as an edge" in {
      val result: JsResult[Edge] = nodeJson.validate[Edge](Edge.edgeReads)
      result.isError should beTrue
      val JsError(errors) = result
      val invalidEdge = JsError.toJson(Seq(
        (__ \ "type") -> Seq(ValidationError("is not of expected type edge"))
      ))
      JsError.toJson(errors) should beEqualTo(invalidEdge)
    }
  }

  val edgeJson = Json.parse(
    """
      |{
      |  "type":"edge",
      |  "name":"myEdge"
      |}
    """.stripMargin)

  val nodeJson = Json.parse(
    """
      |{
      |  "type":"node",
      |  "name":"myNode"
      |}
    """.stripMargin)
}
```

if you don't want to use `asInstanceOf` as a cast you can write the 
`elementReads` instance like so :

```
implicit val elementReads = new Reads[Element] {
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Element] =
    json.validate(
      Node.nodeReads.map(e => e: Element) orElse
      Edge.edgeReads.map(e => e: Element)
    )
}
```

unfortunately, you can't use `_` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. If I'm not wrong, there is no explicit mapping between the JsValues (based on their "elemType" attribute which can either be node or edge) and the case classes, instead the decision is made by trial and error, right? I guess this is a problem since both classes (Edge and Node) have the same structure at the moment (id, name, attributes, ...), the only difference is the type itself. So wouldn't be both edges and nodes transformed to instances of `Node`?

Comment: yes but since you didn't provide the structure of the case classes or the associated reads it is hard to help you further. The reads for each case class can be made to only be valid if the `elemType` has the correct value

Comment: I added some information, hope it helps. A check of `elemType`s value within the `Read` also crossed my mind, but the value itself should not be part of the result (see above for clarification).

Comment: I edited my answer to match the provided information and demonstrate how to check elemType even if it is not part of the final structure.

Comment: Thanks Jean, very helpful, I appreciate your effort. It took a while until I understood what you did but I definitely learned something new today ;)

Comment: my answer does drop the code on one block and doesn't explain it very well. I'll rework it based on your feedback. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks again, Jean, that helped. It's a pity I can upvote your post only once

Comment: @Jean two questions: isn't the message of the `ValidationError` a bit misleading? If `typeRead` fails for both nodes and edges, the error will say that it failed for whatever was checked last (edges in your case) instead of saying it failed for both nodes and edges.. or am I wrong?
The second thing I'm wondering: can multiple `orElse` be chained together (imagine you have nodes, edges and a third entity)? Afair this is/was not possible for `andThen`, could work for `orElse`, though.

Comment: @ceran: yes you can chain as many `orElse` as you want. 
Think of functions:  `f:A=>B orElse g:A=>B orElse h: A=>B` is fine you always end up with `A=>B`,
 `andThen` requires compatible inputs and outputs: `f:A=>B andThen g:B=>C` if you want to andThen h, it has to take C as an input. 
For reads you have a 2nd restriction which is the input has to be a JsValue so you can only `andThen` on `Reads[JsValue]` until the last one.
`Reads[JsArray] andThen Reads[JsValue] andThen Reads[User]` should work. Regarding the error message, you are entirely correct.